Xacro for ROS2 Iron Windows 10
I am running into issues using xacro on Windows 10. It seems like ROS2 Iron does not ship with xacro. Installing it via pip fails as a roslaunch dependency is needed (I believe this is from origianl ROS). I have seen on linux the missing package can be installed using sudo apt install ros-distribution-xacro but obviously this does not work on Windows. Does anyone have a way to use the xacro library on a ROS2 launch file?


Installing it via pip fails as a roslaunch dependency is needed (I believe this is from origianl ROS)

You might try to install it from Github directly using pip, as discussed here and here.
This appears to work for me, installs version 2.0.10 and the executable runs:
pip install git+https://github.com/ros/xacro.git@ros2

The command above installs the package from the ros2 branch, so you don't have the roslaunch dependency.
